# Only one localSetting for toggle switch is executed UWP C#

Tags: c#, xaml, caching

I use 4 toggle switches in my Settings page. I save the value of these in a localSetting so when the user restarts the app the settings still apply. But when I select (set to on) multiple toggle switches when I restart the page, only the first (highest positioned) switch (also the highest in the code) is on.

This is my code:

.cs

```
public Settings()
{
    this.InitializeComponent();

    toggleSwitchPushNotifications.IsOn = Convert.ToBoolean(App.localSettings.Values["PushNotifications"]);

    toggleSwitchFullScreen.IsOn = Convert.ToBoolean(App.localSettings.Values["FullScreen"]);

    toggleSwitchDataCollecting.IsOn = Convert.ToBoolean(App.localSettings.Values["DataCollecting"]);

    toggleSwitchTest.IsOn = Convert.ToBoolean(App.localSettings.Values["Test"]);

}

private void ToggleSwitch_Toggled(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    App.localSettings.Values["PushNotifications"] = toggleSwitchPushNotifications.IsOn;
    App.localSettings.Values["FullScreen"] = toggleSwitchFullScreen.IsOn;
    App.localSettings.Values["DataCollecting"] = toggleSwitchDataCollecting.IsOn;
    App.localSettings.Values["Test"] = toggleSwitchTest.IsOn;
}
```

.XAML

```
<ToggleSwitch Margin="10,10,10,5" Grid.Row="0" Foreground="White" x:Name="toggleSwitchPushNotifications" Header="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Ut eu. " HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Style="{StaticResource ToggleSwitchStyleGreen}" Toggled="ToggleSwitch_Toggled"/>
<ToggleSwitch Margin="10,10,10,5" Grid.Row="1" Foreground="White" x:Name="toggleSwitchFullScreen" Header="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Ut eu. " HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Style="{StaticResource ToggleSwitchStyleGreen}" Toggled=" ToggleSwitch_Toggled"/>
<ToggleSwitch Margin="10,10,10,5" Grid.Row="2" Foreground="White" x:Name="toggleSwitchDataCollecting" Header="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Ut eu. " HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Style="{StaticResource ToggleSwitchStyleGreen}" Toggled=" ToggleSwitch_Toggled"/>
<ToggleSwitch Margin="10,10,10,5" Grid.Row="3" Foreground="White" x:Name="toggleSwitchTest" Header="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Ut eu. " HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Style="{StaticResource ToggleSwitchStyleGreen}" Toggled="ToggleSwitch_Toggled"/>
```

When I put message pop-ups after every toggleswitch.IsOn like this:

```
    toggleSwitchPushNotifications.IsOn = Convert.ToBoolean(App.localSettings.Values["PushNotifications"]);
    MessageDialog msgDialog0 = new MessageDialog("0.");
    msgDialog0.ShowAsync();

    toggleSwitchFullScreen.IsOn = Convert.ToBoolean(App.localSettings.Values["FullScreen"]);
    MessageDialog msgDialog1 = new MessageDialog("1.");
    msgDialog1.ShowAsync();

    toggleSwitchDataCollecting.IsOn = Convert.ToBoolean(App.localSettings.Values["DataCollecting"]);
    MessageDialog msgDialog2 = new MessageDialog("2.");
    msgDialog2.ShowAsync();

    toggleSwitchTest.IsOn = Convert.ToBoolean(App.localSettings.Values["Test"]);
    MessageDialog msgDialog3 = new MessageDialog("3.");
    msgDialog3.ShowAsync();
```

The messages appear in random order so I think that's the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can fix this by using a couple of different methods:

1. By creating an own Toggled-eventhandler for each ToggleSwitch.
2. By using a boolean field to keep track of when the constructor finishes

The problem is now that your **constructor** is "calling" the ToggleSwitch_Toggled -method. This happens when the code sets the toggleSwitchPushNotifications.IsOn. At this point you haven't yet initialized the other ToggleSwitches, so their IsOn is false. This overwrites their current settings.

**Option 1)**

So in XAML, define own Toggled-eventhandler for each ToggleSwitch:

```
    <ToggleSwitch Margin="10,10,10,5" Grid.Row="0" Foreground="White" x:Name="toggleSwitchPushNotifications" Header="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Ut eu. " HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Toggled="ToggleSwitchPushNotifications_OnToggled"/>
    <ToggleSwitch Margin="10,10,10,5" Grid.Row="1" Foreground="White" x:Name="toggleSwitchFullScreen" Header="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Ut eu. " HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Toggled=" ToggleSwitchFullScreen_OnToggled"/>
    <ToggleSwitch Margin="10,10,10,5" Grid.Row="2" Foreground="White" x:Name="toggleSwitchDataCollecting" Header="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Ut eu. " HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top"  Toggled=" ToggleSwitchDataCollecting_OnToggled"/>
    <ToggleSwitch Margin="10,10,10,5" Grid.Row="3" Foreground="White" x:Name="toggleSwitchTest" Header="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Ut eu. " HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top"  Toggled="ToggleSwitchTest_OnToggled"/>
```

And in code behind handle these events for each ToggleSwitch separately:

```
    public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        toggleSwitchPushNotifications.IsOn = Convert.ToBoolean(App.localSettings.Values["PushNotifications"]);
        toggleSwitchFullScreen.IsOn = Convert.ToBoolean(App.localSettings.Values["FullScreen"]);
        toggleSwitchDataCollecting.IsOn = Convert.ToBoolean(App.localSettings.Values["DataCollecting"]);
        toggleSwitchTest.IsOn = Convert.ToBoolean(App.localSettings.Values["Test"]);
    }

    private void ToggleSwitchFullScreen_OnToggled(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        App.localSettings.Values["FullScreen"] = toggleSwitchFullScreen.IsOn;
    }

    private void ToggleSwitchDataCollecting_OnToggled(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        App.localSettings.Values["DataCollecting"] = toggleSwitchDataCollecting.IsOn;
    }

    private void ToggleSwitchTest_OnToggled(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        App.localSettings.Values["Test"] = toggleSwitchTest.IsOn;
    }

    private void ToggleSwitchPushNotifications_OnToggled(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        App.localSettings.Values["PushNotifications"] = toggleSwitchPushNotifications.IsOn;
    }
```

**Option 2)**

Alternatively, you can use a boolean variable to skip calls ToggleSwitch_Toggled from constructor:

```
    private bool initializing = true;
    public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        toggleSwitchPushNotifications.IsOn = Convert.ToBoolean(App.localSettings.Values["PushNotifications"]);
        toggleSwitchFullScreen.IsOn = Convert.ToBoolean(App.localSettings.Values["FullScreen"]);
        toggleSwitchDataCollecting.IsOn = Convert.ToBoolean(App.localSettings.Values["DataCollecting"]);
        toggleSwitchTest.IsOn = Convert.ToBoolean(App.localSettings.Values["Test"]);

        initializing = false;
    }

    private void ToggleSwitch_Toggled(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (initializing) return;

        App.localSettings.Values["PushNotifications"] = toggleSwitchPushNotifications.IsOn;
        App.localSettings.Values["FullScreen"] = toggleSwitchFullScreen.IsOn;
        App.localSettings.Values["DataCollecting"] = toggleSwitchDataCollecting.IsOn;
        App.localSettings.Values["Test"] = toggleSwitchTest.IsOn;
    }
```